# In Web API 2.2: How to use the dependency injector when needed?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api2

I have a question for the article, which probably many of us have read: [Dependency Injection in ASP.NET Web API 2](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/dependency-injection).

Let's assume, that the ProductRepository at some later point in time needs to delegate to some other service. How should ProductRepository  request the concrete instance from the dependency injector at that later time as it is a bad practice to inject the dependency injector itself into the ProductRepository?

Comment: What kind of container are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You can inject the new service inside the ProductRepository just like you injected the IProductRepository into ProductsController.

```
public class ProductRepository : IDisposable
{
    private readonly IOtherService m_OtherService;

    public ProductRepository(IOtherService other_service)
    {
        m_OtherService = other_service;
    }

    ...
}
```

If you register IOtherService successfully in the container, the container would be able to create ProductRepository and ProductsController successfully.

If it is a problem for you to have the OtherService created everytime (maybe you will not use it all the time), you can use the [factory pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern). For example:

```
public interface IOtherServiceFactory
{
    IOtherService Create();
}

public class ProductRepository : IDisposable
{
    private readonly IOtherServiceFactory m_OtherServiceFactory;

    public ProductRepository(IOtherServiceFactory other_service_factory)
    {
        m_OtherServiceFactory = other_service_factory;
    }

    ...
}
```

Now, you can create an instance of OtherService only when you need it.

You have to create an implementation of IOtherServiceFactory and register it with the container.